# Extract content from div with awk/grep

Tags: bash, awk, sed, html-parsing

Assuming following html code.

```
<div class='requirement'>
<div class='req-title'>
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
</div>
</div>
```

I want to extract `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` using tools like `awk` or `sed`, I'm pretty sure it can be done.

I know html parser is the right tools for this job, but this is the only time I'll be dealing with html content.

Comment: When you will try this simple awk solution, you probably will realize that you need to be more detailed in your question / example: `awk '{print $1}' FS='<div |</div>'`

Comment: I want to extract content from class `req-title`

Comment: grep -oP "(?<=<div class='req-title'>).*?(?=<\/div>)" <(cat file.html|tr -d '\n')

Comment: @mouviciel I suggest that that answer is not a useful one in this case. I suggest that you *not* post that answer, because chances are that OP won't understand it.  You and I may laugh at it because we understand what it's saying, but rookies looking for help won't get it.  Instead, point to a something that actually explains the problem. For example, I created http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html to give examples of why HTML+regexes are painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the part you want to print is a single line:

```
$ awk 'f{print; exit} $0=="<div class=\047req-title\047>"{f=1}' file
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

otherwise:

```
$ awk 'f{if ($0=="</div>") exit; print} $0=="<div class=\047req-title\047>"{f=1}' file
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are newlines (HTML does not require that) that is `file.txt` content is

```
<div class='requirement'>
<div class='req-title'>
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
</div>
</div>
```

you might use GNU `AWK` for this task following way

```
awk '/<div class=\x27req-title\x27>/{p=1;next}/<\x2fdiv>/{p=0}p{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Explanation: If `<div class='req-title'>` is encountered set `p` to `1` and go to next line, if `</div>` is encountered set `p` to `0`. If `p` `print` current line. Note that I used hexadecimal for character of special meaning. **Warning** this solution is frail and might fail even for little change, like for example if `"` are used rather than `'`, there is another attribute added to `div` tag &c.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

> I know html parser is the right tools for this job, but this is the
> only time I'll be dealing with html content.

If you are allowed to install tools, please consider using [`hxselect`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxselect.html), it allow extracting tag or content thereof, which are matching CSS selector, in this case it would be as simple as

```
cat file.txt | hxselect -i -c div.req-title
```

`-i` means case insensitive (HTML is case insensitive), `-c` means content only (do not include starting and ending tag) `div.req-title` is [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) meaning `div` which has class `req-title`. This should be more robust than GNU `AWK` solution.

Comment: Thanks, awk did the job. I tried hxselect but it return `End tag </head> doesn't match start tag <meta>`.

Comment: @Liso there is neither `</head>` nor `<meta>` in your example input, if your input is actually HTML mutilated into not being longer legal HTML it is expected that `hxselect` fails

Comment: Regarding use of `\x27` - see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote for why to use `\047` instead.